# mod_rewrite not working on virtual directory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

server: ubuntu 10.4 running apache2

I have a server with mod_rewrite and it works on my virtual hosts.  But I am developing a new site and want to see it on the server before I change the name servers to point to the server.  So in the default site config I added

```
Alias /tester/ "/srv/www/tester.org/wwwroot/"
<Directory "/srv/www/tester.org/wwwroot/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    DirectoryIndex  index.php index.html index.shtml
</Directory>
```

I can see the site when I go to serverIP/tester/ but with the following .htaccess file I am only getting "page not found" errors for anything but index.php.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tester/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /tester/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have spent about 2 hours on this but I can't even guess what I am doing wrong here.  It seems like this should work.  Does anything stand out to anyone?

Comment: can you describe what you are trying to do in more detail?

Comment: is that .htaccess file in `/tester` or `/`?

Comment: .htaccess file is in /srv/www/tester.org/wwwroot/

Comment: I want mod_rewrite to work at server-ip-address/tester/ the same way it works if I had tester.org dns pointing to the server.

Comment: is this an existing VirtualHost configuration for some other website?

Comment: maybe you could specify some example URLs, and what files they should serve in your question...

Comment: also you might want to add the full VirtualHost configuration from `httpd.conf` or `conf.d/somesite.com.conf` for the default site.

Comment: I am not sure where it came from.  It was just called "default" in the sites-available so I added my bit to the bottom and linked it into sites-enabled as "000-default".  Then restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You've set:

```
RewriteBase /tester/
```

But then you're rewriting to the same path:

```
RewriteRule . /tester/index.php [L]
```

So, you're rewriting requests to `/tester//tester/index.php`.

Instead of that, try this:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```